# BroadcastReceiver not receiving BOOT_COMPLETED in AOS

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, bootcompleted

#### My Source Code

WeatherLockReceiver.kt

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class WeatherLockReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var preferenceRepository: PreferenceRepository

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val isEnabled = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
            preferenceRepository.userPreference.first().weatherLockEnabled
        }

        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }

        when (intent.action) {
            Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED,
            Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF -> {
                val activityIntent = Intent(context, WeatherLockActivity::class.java)
                activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
                activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION)
                context.startActivity(activityIntent)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {

        private val intentFilter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)
        }

        fun register(context: Context) {
            context.registerReceiver(WeatherLockReceiver(), intentFilter)
        }

        fun unregister(context: Context) = runCatching {
            context.unregisterReceiver(WeatherLockReceiver())
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

...

<receiver
            android:name="com.skplanet.weatherpong.feature.weatherlock.broadcast.WeatherLockReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

---

How I tried:

1. static registration using Manifest
2. dynamic registration using Context

In both methods, BOOT_COMPLETE was not received.

Why is it not being received?

---

#### Test Device

Samsung Galaxy Z Fold3 (AOS 13)
Android Emulator (AOS 12, 13)

Comment: May Hilt create a new instance of the receiver, can try removing Hilt and re-check